# angularjs filterfilter order by in controller / factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have the following factory:

```
app.factory("ModuleFactory", function (api, $http, $q,filterFilter) {
var moduleList = [];
var categoryList = [];
var moduleTypeList = [];
var academyModuleTypeList = [];
var mostUsed = [];
var lastUpdated = null;
return {
    /**
     * @description This function gets the entire module list for the given users organization.
     * @author Marc Rasmussen
     * @returns {d.promise}
     */
    getList: function () {
        var d = $q.defer();
        if (moduleList.length == 0) {
            $http.get(api.getUrl('module', null))
                .success(function (response) {
                    moduleList = response;
                    lastUpdated = new Date();
                    d.resolve(response);
                });
        }
        else {
            d.resolve(moduleList);
        }
        return d.promise;
    },
    getMostUsed: function () {
        var d = $q.defer();
        if(moduleList.length <= 0){
            this.getList().then(function () {

            })
        }
    }
}
});
```

Now the list `moduleList` contains a list of `objects` in these objects there is a field`num_used`

As you can see i have a created a function called `getMostUsed` this function needs to return the moduleList but ordered by the field `num_used` `desc`.

However i am not quite sure how to use `filterFilter` for this, i know that i could just use `array.sort()` however i wish to use the `angular` function for it if it is possible?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what is filterFilter? The name of a filter you defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming **filterFilter** is a filter you defined somewhere in your app, you can invoke it in your controllers/factories like this.

Import the angular **$filter** service.

```js
app.factory("ModuleFactory", function(api, $http, $q, $filter) {
```

And when you need it you can request your filter and call it like this:

```js
 $filter("filterFilter")(moduleList);
```

More info is available on the angular documentation page for **$filter** service [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter).

If what you want to do is order your **moduleList** by a given property you should be using the **orderBy** filter.

```js
this.getList().then(function(moduleList) {
  $filter('orderBy')(moduleList, '-num_used'); // order descending by the num_used property
})
```

More info about the **orderBy** filter can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Comment: @tovsky can you give an example if we only used the build in $filter method of angular?

Comment: do you mean the default filter called **filter**? @MarcRasmussen

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I added an example using orderBy to order the module list in a descending order. I hope that's what you wanted. :)